# Javascript: Combine function argument with string to reference var

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have vars that look like this:

```
var cardholder = $("#cardholder");
var cardholderInfo = $("#cardholder-Info");
```

And a function (which doesn't currently work) that looks like this:

```
function validateRequired(field){
    //if it's NOT valid
    if(field.val().length < 1){
        field.addClass("field_error");
        fieldInfo.text("(Required)");
        fieldInfo.addClass("error");

        return false;
    }
    //if it's valid
    else{
        field.removeClass("field_error");
        fieldInfo.text("");
        fieldInfo.removeClass("error");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Which I access like:

```
cardholder.keyup(validateRequired(cardholder));
```

I've looked everywhere but I can't find what I need and I'm not really sure what I should be searching for.

I can use the `field` value to access the straight `cardholder` var. But I also want to use the `field` value to then reference `cardholderInfo` so I can manipulate that element in the function.

Comment: Either use two arguments and pass in the cardholderInfo, or make use of javascripts lexical scoping and just use cardholderInfo in your function, if the function is defined in the same scope as cardholderInfo or in a scope which is further down the scope chain starting from cardholderInfo.

Comment: Let's get this straight: what DO you need? I think there is a much easier way of what you are trying...

Comment: @pythonian29033  Please please please never alert, learn how to use the console and log the object with console.log(field) in Chrome and Firefox with firebug you can click through the logged object to inspect it's properties.

Comment: and IMO, `console.dir` is good for firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would call the function like this, passing the second parameter:

```
cardholder.keyup(function () {
    validateRequired(this, cardholderInfo);
});
```

And modify your function to take a second parameter:

```
function validateRequired(field, fieldInfo){
    /* validation stuff */
}
```

Comment: well spotted son!
crap why didn't I see that?

Comment: this in keyup is not a jquery object so trying to do .val() on that will break the code.

Comment: @HMR, you are correct, and knowing this the validation function would have to turn that into a jQuery object if it wants to use `.val()` (perhaps with `$(field)`). My answer is showing how to pass the values to the function (which is what was asked), not actually do the validation.

Comment: It's a good answer, just a heads up to the OP that it'll break the validateRequired function unless called like: validateRequired($(this), cardholderInfo);

Answer (score 2):

No need for the global variables:

```
function validateRequired($cardInfo){
    // You can guess what $cardInfo is
    //if it's NOT valid
    if(this.val().length < 1){
        this.addClass("field_error");
        $cardInfo.text("(Required)");
        $cardInfo.addClass("error");

        return false;
    }
    //if it's valid
    else{
        this.removeClass("field_error");
        $cardInfo.text("");
        $cardInfo.removeClass("error");
        return true;
    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cardholder").keyup(function(){
     validateRequired.call($(this),$("#cardholder-Info"));
  });
});
```

Comment: edit your code in the validate function, it's more erronious than the code in question

Comment: Thanks, didn't see the difference between field and fieldinfo. changed the code

Answer (score 1):

[Don't call](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html#link2) the function you want to bind! If you need to pass an argument to it every time it is called, you either need to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or a function expression:

```
cardholder.keyup(functio(e) {
    return validateRequired(cardholder, cardholderInfo);
});
```

Also you will need a second parameter in your `validateRequired` function to get the `fieldInfo` variable filled:

```
function validateRequired(field, fieldInfo){
    …
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass reference of function in keyup, you do not have to call function

```
cardholder.keyup(function(){
    validateRequired(cardholder)
});
```